# Video recording as like talking tom app

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, video-recording

Im developing a App like Talking Tom.Some dog animation with sound is produced when we touch the Iphone screen .For that i implemented everything but video recording of the iphone screen.I implemented video recording of the iphone screen based on [here](http://purplelilgirl.tumblr.com/post/10974345146/mini-tutorial-how-to-capture-video-of-iphone-app-in)..It recorded dog animation without sound.What i have to do to include audio with the video file?Is there any sample code available?

If u develop your App using cocos2D,the sample code [here](http://purplelilgirl.tumblr.com/post/10974345146/mini-tutorial-how-to-capture-video-of-iphone-app-in) would be useful!

Answer (score 1):

Use AVAudioRecorder in the AVFoundation framework. Import the AVFoundation framework and

Conform to the AVAudioRecorderDelegate
Create an AVAudioRecorder instance and a NSURL instance
**SAMPLE CODE

Recording:

```
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil]; // assign it to recording session
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil]; // activate it!
      NSMutableDictionary* recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
       [recordSetting setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4]    forKey:AVFormatIDKey]; // assign this special hardware component as the function to record
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0]
    forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; //44100 is the sample rate 
   [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2]
    forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey]; // same thing
   tmpFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
      [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:
    [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.0f.%@",
     [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] * 1000.0,
      @"caf"]]]; // how we identify the audio written to the file to play later
      recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:tmpFile settings:recordSetting
    [recorder setDelegate:self];
   [recorder prepareToRecord];
   [recorder record];
```

PLAYING:

```
    AVAudioSession * audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
   [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
       [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
      AVAudioPlayer * player =
       [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:tmpFile error:nil]; // takes recording data from tmpFile where we wrote the recording in
      [player prepareToPlay];
     [player play];
```

Thats just some sample code.... to help you but otherwise read the documentation
Im not sure how you could animate the mouth or if you wanted to change the pitch but this is a start to recording